# How to rotate two images and place them side by side?

Tags: graphics, floats, rotating, sidebyside

Here is what I want to achieve on a portrait oriented page:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can put each picture with caption in a `minipage`, and rotate it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \hfill
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{Caption of first picture}
      \label{fig:First}
    \end{minipage}
  }\hfill
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{Caption of second picture}
      \label{fig:First}
    \end{minipage}
  }\hfill\strut
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]